# distance along the cubic curve $y=x^3$

Tags: calculus

> Consider the function $g(x)=x^3.$ Estimate the distance along the curve $[0,2]$ using the straight line distance on the interval $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$

What I have tried:

When $x=0$, Then $y=0$

When $x=1$, Then $y=1$

When $x=2,$ Then $y=8$

So we have to find distance between the points $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, which is $\sqrt{2}$

We also have to find the distance between the points $(1,1)$ to $(2,8)$, which is $\sqrt{1^2+7^2}=5\sqrt{2}$

So total estimated distance $\sqrt{2}+5\sqrt{2}=6\sqrt{2}$.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your estimate is correct based on the question. It represents the total length of the two green lines

[image]

We also have a method to calculate the actual arc length. It requires integration. You may see the method described in the 2nd part of the problem in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829949/823370) answer.

So, the arc length would be given by the definite integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{9x^{4}+1}\cdot dx$$

Which comes out to be around $8.63032922223$

And your estimate is approximately $8.485281$

Now that depends upon your error tolerance if you consider it as a good estimate or not. Cheers :)

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last line, because the problem is clearly asking for the estimate using the two approximations, and so I don't think error tolerance matters. I think only whether the answer correctly answers the question matters. However, nice job for including the arc length function.

Comment: I may estimate that as sqrt68 or sqrt50 or 1 4 6 anything.... Bcz that is just an estimate. It actually depends upon the error that you call it a good or a bad estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer, $6\sqrt{2}$, is correct, based on the question given. By the way, the arc length formula, which allows you to give the precise answer, is $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\ dx$, where $a$ is the lower bound and $b$ is the upper bound. @Soumyadwip Chanda gave more detailed calculations using the arc length formula.